# GNOME Shell 3.4.1 change shortcut to navigate between applications (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: 12.04, gnome, shortcut-keys

I want to change the shortcut to navigate between applications on my Gnome shell 3.4.1 from Alt+TAB to Super+TAB
( Since I RDP to a windows box sometimes and it "eats" away the ALT+TAB)

I followed the instructions on the Gnome website and changed the navigation shortcut from Alt+Tab to Super+Tab .. but it still is not working... even after restarting the gnome-shell

Any ideas ?

Comment: I use the plain vanilla Ubuntu, and I've re-defined the same keyboard short-cut using CCSM and that works...  How did you re-define the short-cut?

Comment: thru the system settings. "Keyboard" item

Comment: Try CompizConfig Settings Manager (unsure myself if that exsists for Gnome) in the application switcher plug-in and change the [alt][tab] to [Super][Tab] and that will remove [alt][tab] as well as adding [Super][Tab]... Report back whether that worked or not.

Comment: I do not think Compiz can help ... I think its more of a dconf-editor setting that i need to change.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to reflect that you don't want any compiz solutions in the first place!  :-(

Comment: Compiz would have been a lazy workaround. But isn't Linux all about hacking stuff ;-) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open dconf-editor and changing the setting for

`org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings switch-applications` to the value `['<Super>Tab', '<Alt>Tab']` worked for me